# How to export variables from ssh session within git bash (for Windows) after exiting ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

Can I export variables from ssh session within git bash (for Windows) after exiting ssh?

What I want to do is something like this.

1. Execute git bash for Windows.
2. Execute ssh.

```
$ ssh root@192.168.xx.xx
```

3. Set some value(s) to variable(s).

```
root@localhost:~# A=1
root@localhost:~# echo $A
1
```

4. Exit ssh.

```
root@localhost:~# exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.xx.xx closed.
```

5. Use the value I set in step 3 on git bash.

- desired result

```
$ echo $A
1
```

- actual result

```
$ echo $A
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'eval' command to get varibales like this:

```
vars=$(ssh user@server "a=value1; b=value2; echo \"a=\$a b=\$b\"")

eval $vars

echo $a
echo $b
```

result:

```
value1
value2
```